# dojo drag and drop: don't want to sort items

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

I have a dojo.dnd Source object that I just want to list out normally, without the user being able to sort the objects. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `selfAccept="false"` (and probably `copyOnly="true"`) too in your Source declaration.  That will prevent the user from re-ordering your list.

If you want to prevent items from getting dragged into it, just set the `accepts` parameter to something that you don't have.

You can see an example of it on [dojotoolkit](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojo/tests/dnd/test_dnd.html).  Just do a search for `selfAccept`

Comment: I'm using dojo.dnd.Source to display a list of draggable items, and dojo.dnd.Target as a droppable area which accepts items from the Source objects. In the Source list, however, I don't want users to be able to move the items around, they should only be able to drag the item out and drop it into the Target object. I didn't see any properties for Source that seem to disable sorting...any ideas? Thanks for your help for the other question too, btw.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think about selfAccept. The API documentation is a bit sparse, dontcha think?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty spotty in parts.  I tend to look at the tests directory and/or docs.dojocampus when I need information.  Failing that I go to the source.